# Why is it that bcrypt (3.1.11 x86-mingw32) keeps showing up even after uninstalling it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cmd, rubygems, bcrypt

Is it because of bundle install? Does bcrypt has a function to reinstall it somehow within the code? The code runs fine after I uninstall it but I am not really tracking it all and it seems like something keeps reinstalling it back in.

Comment: It's probably because of dependencies. Probably some gem uses bcrypt so after you run `bundle install` it installs it back.

Comment: How did you uninstall that gem? Is it still included in your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Oh wow, i didn't know about that. But I will see. I uninstalled it through terminal tho